# Axios Network error on post request React.js but works on Postman

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, axios-mock-adapter

I did a post request in Postman with adding Api-key in header from Authorization options which works completely fine but when i tried to do the same thing in React.js it gives me Network error. I think i'm missing anythink in my post request but don't know what.

Note :- I don't have the access to the server so can't change anything in their.

**Code for request**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';



function Card() {

    useEffect(() => {

        axios.post("url is provided", { data: "" },
            {
                withCredentials: true,
                headers:
                {
                    'Api-key': 'api-key is provided',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            }
        )
            .then((response) => console.log(response, "response"))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err, "err"))

    }, [])


    return (
        <div className='card'>
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Card
```

**Post Man**

[image]

**Error in Console**

[image]

**Network tab**
[image]

Comment: The last screenshot is not the one for the console error.

Comment: @technophyle, apologies for screenshot please have a look i have fixed it

Comment: Yeah, if you can upload a screenshot of error in the Network tab, that'd be helpful.

Comment: @JaromandaX - it does say status 200 in network console but in the response tab it is empty and i needed the token from there like it is in postman query

Comment: You should screenshot the one with the red color. Not the OPTIONS request.

Comment: OPTIONS is a CORS preflight - that WONT have any response data - check the response in the request that uses POST method

Comment: @JaromandaX, i have change the screenshot and there is no request with post method in the network tab, don't know what's wrong now?

Comment: chromes developer tools suck - try using firefox

Comment: That's not the correct one either. Click through all red ones and see if Response tab has anything useful.

Comment: @technophyle, it is confirm that it is CORS erro but how can i fix this without access to the server files?

Comment: @SharanjeetSingh The proper fix should be on the server. For temporary testing, you can install CORS extension on Chrome, that can help you bypass the security check.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `create-create-app` for the client, you can use a proxy so that the request will go like this:

Client -> React Server (Proxy) -> Backend endpoint

This way, it will look like you're sending a request to your server and the browser doesn't complain.

Add a proxy field in `package.json`

```
"proxy": "https://backend-enpoint-here.com/"
```

now in the frontend you can simply call

```
axios.post("/api/some-endpoint")
```